# If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n + x_{n+1} =0 $ is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$?

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n + x_{n+1} =0 $ is $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n}=0$?

If $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n - x_{n+1} =0 $ then I would say $x_n$ is bounded therefore true,

but I have no idea where to start. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hint: consider $y_n=(-1)^nx_n$.

Comment: Note that $x_n$ need not be bounded even if $\lim_{n\to \infty} (x_{n+1}-x_n)=0$; see for example $x_n=\sqrt{n}$

Comment: +1 Even though your analysis was flawed, and your conclusion was dead wrong, I still upvoted, because you **meta-cheated**.  That is, you assumed (correctly) that the information given in the problem was pertinent, and you attempted to stretch your intuition around the information.  From my perspective, the fact that you went off the rails, re Mindlack's comment is **irrelevant**.

Comment: I am super confused by so many different perspectives.... But for sure I now realized that $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n - x_{n+1} =0$ does not guarantee that it is convergent... Then how would I show that when $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n - x_{n+1} =0$, $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_n}{n} =0$?

Comment: @user2661923  I edited your answer in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32433/was-my-mathse-answer-appropriate.  By the way, what's the meaning of "meta cheated" (I cannot find its meaning by searching google)?

Comment: @RiverLi It is a term that no one uses but me.  The idea, which I think applies to all math study at or below the undergraduate level, is that you can attack a problem with a series of questions/assumptions: (1) The conjecture to be proven (for example) is probably true (2) The conjecture can proven (or the problem can be solved) in a reasonable way (3) The theorems or previously solved problems leading up to the problem/conjecture may well provide a set of pertinent tools ...see next comment

Comment: @RiverLi (4) The author/teacher intentionally presented the question at a particular moment as an application of the prior material (5) Related to [4] What is the *intent* of the questioner? (6) If no elegant insight re the problem presents itself, take investigative **baby-steps** to see what is happening in special cases, look for a pattern, try to form a hypothesis, try to prove the hypothesis (7) Your primary weapon in math (especially combinatorics/probability) is your intuition - always look for ways to stretch your intuition, and always look for ways to use your intuition vs the problem

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint by @Mindlack is half the solution. For $y_n=(-1)^n x_n$, we have $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(y_{n+1}-y_n)=0\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{y_n}{n}=0,$$ the implication is by the [Stolz–Cesàro theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem). Thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n/n=0.$

Comment: But how would you prove that $\lim \limits_{n to \infty} y_{n+1} - y_n =0 $ leads to $\lim \limits_{n to \infty} \frac{y_n}{n}=0 $

Comment: Nvm. I got ti!!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a sequence built up of x(n) and then construct another one with the rule

```
x(n)=x(n) for n dividable by 2
x(n)=-x(n) for n not dividable by 2

x(0)+x(1)=x(0)-x(0)=0

x(2n)+x(2n+1)=x(2n)-x(2n)=0

x(2n+1)+x(2n+2)=x(2n+1)-x(2n+1)=0
```

So the limit of the derived third sequence `x(n)+x(n+1)` is fo sure zero since all individual members in the sequence are zero.

But our introductory sequence has only the attribute to be a sequence. We just used the rule to construct new sequences from one, particularly selected sequence.

We too used the axiom the indices are unlimited and the mightiness of integer used to enumeration is aleph0.

The first part of our rule set can be renumerated. Now extent the attributes of our sequences:

(a) the sequence is unbounded without any limitation to positive infinity, can be negative infinity too.
(b) the sequence is bounded.
(c) the sequence is convergent.

In case (a) we will find an M in the integers that are always bigger than an n we can select and the magnitude of the sequence element will exceed our bounds.

In cases (a) and (b) we select an n from the indices and name that n. For that n we can find from the definition of convergent sequences that there exists an epsilon positive such that our sum is smaller than that epsilon.

Consider the cases:

```
(i)   x(n)<0, x(n+1)>0 then x(n+1)>x(n)+x(n+1)
(ii)  x(n)>0, x(n+1)>0 then x(n)+x(n+1)>x(n)>0
(iii) x(n)>0, x(n+1)<0 then x(n)>x(n)+x(n+1)
(iv)  x(n)<0, x(n+1)<0 then x(n)+x(n+1)<x(n)<0
```

But we like a bound for `x(n)/n`. Because n in positive integer in our enumeration
the product or quotient has the sign of `x(n)`

```
x(n)>0 => x(n)/n>0
x(n)<0 => x(n)/n<0
```

In the cases (ii) and (iv) we are ready, the to be proven lemmata is correct by the majorant or upper bound criteria.

In the two other cases, we have a lower limit.

There is usually a criterion about absolute convergence in such courses. So we just consider the absolute sequence of the given sequence `|x(n)|`. Then these two cases lead to the already considered and proven cases. We just need to know, that if a sequence is an absolute convergent than it is convergent without the absolut function too.

The question shows that the requirement for a sequence to have `lim x(n)+x(n+1) = 0` is just only as strong as `lim x(n)/n = 0` and not as erroneously assumed as strong as `lim x(n) = 0` and there is range in between depending on the sequence under consideration. We can prove something in the inverse direction, from `lim x(n)/n` does not follow that `lim x(n)+x(n+1) = 0` in general.

Example for the divergent case:

```
x(n)=+1/(2) for n dividable by 2
x(n)=−+1/(2) for n not dividable by 2
```

x(2n)+(2n+1)=2n+1/(4n)-(2n+1)+1/(4n)=-1+1/(2n)
x(2n+1)+(2n+2)=-2n-1+1/(2(2n+1))+(2n+2)+1/(2(2n+2)=1+1/(4n+2)+1/(4n+4))

The sequence condition is not fulfilled because the first part sequence converges to -1 and the second one to 1, but both converge. So things can be rather complicated too for this.